# How to associate new domain class using .properties?

Tags: grails

I have the following classes:

```
class Employer {
    static hasMany = [employees: Employee]
}

class Employee {
    String name
    static belongsTo = [employer: Employer]
}
```

I try to save some JSON from the front end (the actual code is a bit more dynamic):

```
params = {
    employer: 1,
    name: 'Test'
}

def save = {
    def employee = new Employee()
    employee.properties = params;
    employee.save()
}
```

However, the save fails because the employer cannot be set from the id. (Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.Integer' to required type 'Employer') Is there a way to make that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure of your JSON is incorrect.  It would need to be something more like:

```
'employer':{
  'class':'Employer','id':1
}
```

Comment: I have been able to get it working by using {"employer.id": 1} but that's more work on the front end than I would like. Either way it seems like something that grails should be able to handle... if no one has a better answer I'll probably accept this one.

Comment: `{"employer.id": 1}` is the answer. Why is it more work then your suggested `{"employer": 1}`?